# TextBox not getting proper focus

Tags: c#, wpf

First I don't think this is a duplicate of other posts for getting `TextBox`, setting focus to caret to blink and have keyboard focus. I have tried every method I saw and they did not work.

I have button that adds a path to a `Listbox`. The list box items are a custom control that has `TextBlock` and `Listbox` properties. Normally it displays the `TextBlock`. When clicked the `TextBlock` is hidden and the `Listbox` is made visible to edit. What I want to happen is when the add button is clicked it should create an item and the item should be in edit mode. When I do this I get the `IBeam` but it is not blinking so I think it does not have proper focus. I have tried many different ways to do this.
When I click on the item it works properly.

Here is `AddSearchPathMouseUp`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle Add search path mouse up
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="MouseButtonEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void AddSearchPathMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchPathList.Focus();
        SearchPathList.SelectedItem = null;

        var mouseDownEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseDownEvent
        };
        var mouseUpEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent
        };


        var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Rtx64Dir") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemDrive") ?? "C:\\";
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        AddPathToList(di.Root.Name, true);

        var listItem = SearchPathList.Items[SearchPathList.Items.Count - 1] as ListBoxItem;
        if (listItem == null) return;

        listItem.Focus();
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            SearchPathList.SelectedIndex = SearchPathList.Items.Count - 1;

            var browseEditText = listItem.Content as BrowseEditText;
            if (browseEditText == null) return;

            browseEditText.EditMode = true;
            browseEditText.TextEditText.CaretIndex = browseEditText.Text.Length + 1;

            browseEditText.RaiseEvent(mouseDownEvent);
            browseEditText.RaiseEvent(mouseUpEvent);
        }
    }
```

Here is the `userControls.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="Rtx64ControlPanel.BrowseEditText"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="790">
<Grid Width="790">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextEditText" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
    <TextBlock x:Name ="TextBlockText" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button x:Name="BrowseButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content=" ... " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Here is codebehind for the user control

```
   /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for BrowseEditText.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class BrowseEditText
{
    private bool _editMode;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [edit mode].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if [edit mode]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool EditMode
    {
        get { return _editMode; }
        set
        {
            _editMode = value && Security.IsUserAdministrator;

            TextBlockText.Visibility = _editMode ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
            TextEditText.Visibility = _editMode ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
            BrowseButton.Visibility = _editMode ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
            if (!_editMode) return;

            TextEditText.Focusable = true;
            TextEditText.Focus();
            Keyboard.Focus(TextEditText);
        }
    }

    private String _text;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The text.</value>
    public String Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            TextBlockText.Text = Text;
            TextEditText.Text = Text;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BrowseEditText"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public BrowseEditText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EditMode = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a potential [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... perhaps more context or maybe even a visual as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The actual problem is I get an Ibeam for the TextBox but it does not blink and I can not type into it.